# How to check user password in Joomla 3?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm developing a Joomla 3.3 plugin.
Now I want to check whether the username and password that user has entered is correct or not.
I tried **JUser->login**. the problem is when the username and password don't match, this function automatically redirects user to login page and doesn't show the error message provided by plugin.
Is there any solution to check that username and password match without using login ?

this is my original code:

```
$cfg = new JConfig();

    if(isset($_REQUEST['username']) && isset($_REQUEST['passwd']))
    {
        $_SESSION['lockuser'] = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $_SESSION['lockpass'] = md5($_REQUEST['passwd']);
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['lockuser']) && isset($_SESSION['lockpass']))
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $db->setQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #__users WHERE `username`=' . $db->Quote($_SESSION['lockuser']) . ' AND `password`=' . $db->Quote($_SESSION['lockpass']));
        $db->query();
        if($db->loadResult())
        {
            return;
        }else{
            $error = "Wrong username/password !!!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just curious, but why are you transferring the request vars to session first? Perhaps it's a Joomla specific thing, but is that even necessary?

Comment: You might get some insight at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/is-it-possible-to-change-the-joomla-user-authentication-algorithm/5530#5530